# Big Decimal to string

Tags: java, tostring, bigdecimal

I am trying to upload an excel field whose column contains more than 250 digits. When I enter the value in the excel, it automatically converts it to this format
1.23456789012345E+256 And when I try to read the value using the Big Decimal's toPlainString method, it returns all 0s after 15 digits. The same works fine if I give the entire number without the exponent.
How do I get the entire number when the input is 1.23456789012345E+256 ?

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(String.valueOf("1.23456789012345E+256"));
System.out.println( bd.toPlainString());
```

Returned String

*123456789012345*00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Comment: What do you mean by "the entire number"? The original "entire number", before it was rounded to `[some value]E+256`?

Comment: I was able to get the original number before it was rounded off by prefixing a single quote to the number '1233278238789787

Answer (score 4):

> How do I get the entire number when the input is 1.23456789012345E+256

That is the entire number as a BigDecimal.

1.23456789012345E+256 == 12345678901234500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

---

Why are you using BigDecimal? Excel uses `double` and it would make more sense to preserve the type it uses.

```
double d = 1.23456789012345E+256;
System.out.println(d);
```

prints

```
1.23456789012345E256
```

Comment: I need to save the actual number in the data base. thats why trying to read the value using the big decimal's to plain string method. please let me know if there is a better way to do it

Comment: If the number is a `double` 1.23456789012345E+256 leave it as that value and type. Converting it risks either changing the value or confusing anyone trying to use it. ;)

Comment: You can't convert infinity or NaN as a BigDecimal.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, precision is lost.  You will have to store your values in a higher precision format.

Comment: I don't see any precision lost, they are the same (see my answer) What higher precision than BigDecimal do you suggest?

Comment: Pete: I think his implication is, how does he restore the original number

Comment: I wouldn't convert the value to another type so there is no need to "restore" it either.

Comment: The problem arises only when the numbers gets converted into exponential format. I am able to retrieve the original number if its without exponents. For instance, i tried out the same by replacing the exponent with 350 4s..

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the original number before it was rounded off by prefixing a single quote to the number '1233278238789787

Answer (score 0):

Try with Double instead of double. also its based on your database column data type. If your database allows 1.23456789012345E+256, then Double will help you, if database column is Float.